# Join two tables based on non-sharing values in chosen column

Tags: perl, columns, merge

I have been using  "Perl for biologists with little computer coding knowledge" from site called Scriptome (Harvard).  It gives great Perl one-liners to achieve desired functions which runs on Unix line command.   One very useful script that I use is titled: 
"Join two tables based on columns sharing a value (merge_lines_based_on_shared_column)" 
This works great, but sometimes I want the exact opposite.  IE: the generation of tables where given values from two columns do not match.  For the former, I copy/paste the code they provide below.   I would be most grateful if someone can help me.

### myScirpt.pl

```
$col1=1;
$col2=0;
($f1,$f2)=@ARGV;
open(F2,$f2);
while (<F2>) {
    s/\r?\n//;
    @F=split /\t/, $_;
    $line2{$F[$col2]} .= "$_\n"
};
$count2 = $.;
open(F1,$f1);
while (<F1>) {
    s/\r?\n//;
    @F=split /\t/, $_;
    $x = $line2{$F[$col1]};
    if ($x) {
        $num_changes = ($x =~ s/^/$_\t/gm);
        print $x;
        $merged += $num_changes
    }
} warn "\nJoining $f1 column $col1 with $f2 column $col2\n"
    . "$f1: $. lines\n"
    . "$f2: $count2 lines\n"
    . "Merged file: $merged lines\n";
```

Then I run it like,

```
myScript.pl Input-file1.txt Input-file2.txt > Merge-file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This script is pretty poor you should specify exactly where you found it so it can be fixed. In this example

```
$x = $line2{$F[$col1]};
```

Is writing to a global undeclared hash called `%line2`. Then it later checks to see if that value is present here,

```
if ($x) {
```

You probably want to change that block to

```
if (!$x) {
    print $F[$col1];
}
```